# Playing a youtube video from a UIWebView crashes after the video starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, youtube

My video crashes after a 2seg of playing the video. It's giving me Thread 4 **WebThread:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address0x20)**

This is how I'm doing it..

```
UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kElementX, kElementY, kElementWidth, 120)];
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoView.opaque = NO;
videoView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
videoView.delegate = self;

[cell.contentView addSubview:videoView];

NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                       <head>\
                       <style type=\"text/css\">\
                       iframe {position:absolute; top:0%%; margin-top:0px;}\
                       body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                       </style>\
                       </head>\
                       <body>\
                       <div id=\"player\">\
                       <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"420px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                       </div>\
                       <script>\
                       var tag = document.createElement('script');\
                       tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";\
                       var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\
                       firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);\
                       var player;\
                       var myVideoId = document.getElementById('%@')\
                       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {\
                       player = new YT.Player('player', {\
                       height: '100%%',\
                       width: '100%%',\
                       videoId: myVideoId,\
                       events: {\
                       'onReady': onPlayerReady,\
                       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange\
                       }\
                       });\
                       }\
                       function onPlayerReady(event) {\
                       event.target.playVideo();\
                       }\
                       function stopVideo() {\
                       player.stopVideo();\
                       }\
                       </script>\
                       </body>\
                       </html>", self.url, self.url];

[self.videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
[self.videoView setMediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay:YES];
```

If you guys need more info please let me know.. I tried different ways but it keep crashing I dont know why..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NSString *exampleUrlString = @"https://www.youtube.com/embed/2bfP3TZHUzY?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent";
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:exampleUrlString]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:webView];
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    NSString *exampleUrlString = @"https://www.youtube.com/embed/2bfP3TZHUzY?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent";
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:exampleUrlString]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:webView];

    return cell;
}
```

Don't forget..

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return the webView height
    return 150;
}
```

Do you see Neymar NOW ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: still getting the same problem, and I even tried your answer within my viewdidload which I feel it shouldnt make much of a difference..

Comment: Then you error is somewhere else. See updated screenshot. And a word of advice. When people try to help you and you don't appreciate it, no one will want to help you. I don't know you, I don't need to help you, but I did. And you said "I feel it shouldnt make much of a difference..?"

Comment: it shouldnt make much of a difference between setting it on the viewdidload or tableview that was all I never miss appreciate help

Comment: See the updated screenshot so you know that the code works and your Thread 4 error is from somewhere else you didn't mention in you question.

Comment: actually it was a video problem, it wasn't your code or mine :S lol